# Boostrap Nav + Carousel + Footer keep relative heights

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I would like to know whether it is possible to keep relative heights from the three main components of a home html. In this case, bootstrap nav + carousel + footer. I would like to modify the height of the carousel so it is always around 70% of the screen with the other 20% for the nav and 10% for the footer. There is no image resizing problems since the carousel has only one background color and it is not an image. The html structure looks like this:

Here is the fiddle:

```
 <div></div>
https://jsfiddle.net/q4t8bupc/
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Please check this.

```css
.header{height:20vh; background:#666}
.content{height:70vh; background:#ed0000;}
.footer{height:10vh; background:#03C;}
```

```html
<div class="header"></div>
<div class="content"></div>
<div class="footer"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it does not work well with the carousel: https://jsfiddle.net/q4t8bupc/1/ check it out...